# How to use the audio file response directly into the azure speech recognition without saving it in local using python?

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text

If I am using any pullaudiostream it's not working properly (get_property and callback is not working)

I need to use the audio response to convert to text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`PushAudioInputStream` is a class provided by the Azure Speech SDK that represents a memory-backed push audio input stream used for custom audio input configurations. It allows you to stream audio data directly into the recognizer as an alternative to using a microphone or file input.

```py
stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream()
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)
```

Comment: It is showing that 'io.BytesIO'/'bytes' object has no attribute '_handle'

Comment: Please share code in the question that you are trying and share the error details.

Comment: audio_file = request.files['file']
    audio_file1= audio_file.read()
    audio_stream = io.BytesIO()
    filen = audio_file.filename
    audio_stream.write(audio_file1)
    stream=speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(audio_stream)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=stream)

    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="sub_key", region="region")
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

Comment: error     
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute '_handle'

Comment: You cannot construct PushAudioStream using BytesIO object, see API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.pushaudioinputstream?view=azure-python

And check the sample for push stream https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py#LL555C43-L555C43

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78171624/process-audio-from-byte-stream-or-file-without-saving-to-disk-azure-speech-sdk-p/78179651#78179651

Refer this